# Why my animation property is not working in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to use animation property in CSS to move a div from left to right. But the code isnt working.

I am new to animation property in CSS. I had refer to some article in W3Schools and StackOverFlow but still didnt make it.

```css
#title {
  font-size: 8.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: goldenrod;
  animation: move 3s ease;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="title">Soy Boos</div>
```

The word Soy Boos should move from left to right

Answer (score 4):

Hey @Gan read about [left property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp) from the w3schools it have the following definition and usages

---

The left property affects the horizontal position of a positioned element. This property has **no effect** on **non-positioned** elements.

• If position: absolute; or position: fixed; - the left property sets the left edge of an element to a unit to the left of the left edge of its nearest positioned ancestor.

• If position: relative; - the left property sets the left edge of an element to a unit to the left/right of its normal position.

• If position: sticky; - the left property behaves like its position is relative when the element is inside the viewport, and like its position is fixed when it is outside.

• If position: static; - the left property has no effect.

---

So you just have to add `position` attribute to your `#title` element for `left` attribute to work...

```css
#title{
  font-size: 8.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: goldenrod;
  animation: move 3s ease; 
  animation-direction: normal;
  position:relative; /* this one */
}

@keyframes move{
  from {left:0;}
  to {left:200px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="title">Soy Boos</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `position:absolute` or `position:relative` to **#title**

because in order to work `left`  you need to specify a position like `absolute` or `relative`

```css
#title{
  font-size: 8.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: goldenrod;
  animation: move 3s ease; 
  animation-direction: normal;
  position:absolute;
}

@keyframes move{
  from {left:0;}
  to {left:200px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="title">Soy Boos</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#title {
  font-size: 8.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: goldenrod;
  animation: move 3s ease;
  animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Satish welcome to SO, please provide *how* these snippet works or include the source of it, your answer is too good...